# JsonCpp wrapper

Tags: c++, class, implementation, wrapper, jsoncpp

### Problem Description

I am trying to write wrapper for [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/). My wrapper must have following functions

- `Parse(const string& input)`
- `GetString(string& output, const string name, bool optional = true)`
- `SetString(const string& value, const string name, bool optional = true)`
- `GetObject(const string& objectName)`

I have call my wrapper class `Parser`

```
class Parser
{
private:
    Json::Value mJsonObject;

public:
    bool Parse(const string& input);
    bool GetString(string& output, const string name, bool optional = true);
    bool SetString(const string& value, const string name, bool optional = true);
    Parser& GetObject(const string& objectName);
};
```

In the code I want to write following:

```
void foo()
{
    Parser::GetObject("IN").GetObject("Params").SetString("Param1", "this is json");
}
```

by calling this I want to create following JSON

```
{
    "IN" : {
        "Params" : {
            "Param1":"this is json"
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

***How I must implement `GetObject` and `SetString` function in order to get expected result ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, good luck :)

I'm not sure what exactly you're having trouble with, but here are some things you need to do:

- `GetObject` returns `*this`, so that you can chain `GetObject` calls
- `Json::Value` contains an `operator[]` which does what you expect - get the associated value, creating it if it doesn't exist. `GetObject` can simply wrap that. Remember to update your local `mJsonObject` with the child object.
- `SetString` simply wraps `GetObject` followed by constructing a new `Json::Value` via string argument

Comment: Actually, I would advise that `GetObject` *not* return `*this`, but return *another* proxy object (possibly of the same type).